# Report: Records that have been updated by owner

Tags: reports, custom-reports

Is there a way to go through and create a report (either in Civi or using Drupal Views) that shows what records have been updated by the owner themselves? Such as them going in and updating an employer or address?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such report that filters by logged in user and no integration with views as well AFAIK.

If you want detailed change log than you (system has logging enabled) then you can use [Extended logging report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-logging-report). And manipulate report parameter like

```
/civicrm/report/contact/extendedloggingsummary?reset=1&force=1&display_name_value=abc&display_name_op=has
```

Inbuild report

```
/civicrm/report/logging/contact/summary?force=1&reset=1&display_name_value=abc&display_name_id_op=has
```

If you don't have logging enabled than you can use Database log report and build report parameter

```
/civicrm/report/contact/log?reset=1&force=1&sort_name_value=abc&sort_name_op=has
```

If you want to support filtering by logged in user in one of the two above report than you add filter using selectWhereClause or alterReportVar hook.

Support to views won't be difficult by writing an module extending to civicrm entity module. If you can extend views module to support change log than you can filter or retrieve various data of the contact.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Yea, writing a module is way beyond my ability. I know enough PHP and such to be able to do some minor things, but that's it.

Comment: Do you have logging enabled?

Comment: Yes, but we're talking about going back a year or more into the data. The logs don't go back that far. The information is in the Activity listing, so we thought maybe somewhere we could create a report based on that.

Comment: Just a note to say that in 2023 on Civi 5.65 the [Extended Logging Report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-logging-report) extension is broken and hasn't been updated since 2012. I too am looking for a solution to provide detailed reports for specific fields from Civi's detailed logs (logging enabled).